# How to catch error seperate for two await within one try catch

Tags: javascript, async-await, react-redux, try-catch

I have a function with two await promises runing in one try catch block in Redux actions. I was only catching the error for adding new project. **If I want to catch the error from participant add, how should I do?** The add participant function only run if a new project is created and once it successes, the participant can get the new created project ID, that's why I put these two await together.

```
const handleProjectParticipant = async (project, participant) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const resultProject = await createNewProject(project)
        dispatch({ type: PROJECT_ADD, payload: resultProject })
        const newProject_id = resultProject.id
        participant.project_id = newProject_id
        const resultParticipant = await addParticipant(participant)
        dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ADD, payload: resultParticipant })
    }
    catch(e) {
        dispatch({ type: PROJECT_ADD_FAIL, payload: e})
        //want to catch error for add participant
        //dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ADD_FAIL, payload: e})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest another try/catch in the first:

```
const handleProjectParticipant = async (project, participant) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const resultProject = await createNewProject(project)
        dispatch({ type: PROJECT_ADD, payload: resultProject })
        const newProject_id = resultProject.id
        participant.project_id = newProject_id
        try {
            const resultParticipant = await addParticipant(participant)
            dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ADD, payload: resultParticipant })
        } catch(e) {
            dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ADD_FAIL, payload: e})
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
        dispatch({ type: PROJECT_ADD_FAIL, payload: e})
    }
}
```

Or you could just do something like:

```
const handleProjectParticipant = async (project, participant) => async (dispatch) => {
    let handleError = (e) => dispatch({ type: PROJECT_ADD_FAIL, payload: e})
    try {
        const resultProject = await createNewProject(project)
        dispatch({ type: PROJECT_ADD, payload: resultProject })
        const newProject_id = resultProject.id
        participant.project_id = newProject_id
        handleError = (e) => dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ADD_FAIL, payload: e})
        const resultParticipant = await addParticipant(participant)
        dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ADD, payload: resultParticipant })
    }
    catch(e) {
        handleError(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: any way without nest?